# Laravel Artisan::queue not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a artisan command signature named 'import:excelfile'

I want to run that command inside my controller. Everything is working fine in my controller. But the Artisan::queue('import:excelfile') is not running from controller. But its running from CLI perfectly. Where's the problem?

Please look at my codes

controller method code 
http://pastebin.com/45dj179H

artisan code
http://pastebin.com/zNCtQKZ0

Thanks

Comment: I would bet, that the problem is in the queue driver configurations. OR try to change ` $file_path = 'public/files/' . $file->file_name;` to: ` $file_path = public_path('files/' . $file->file_name);`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks you guys for response.

actually I am neither getting any error nor its failing. Just artisan queue not running from controller. But php artisan import:excelfile was running and working from CLI .

Now I commanded php artisan queue:listen and after it the artisan queue is running from controller :)

Comment: I am having this same problem right now. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Command works immediately, instead of queuing

Answer (score 5):

Try something along the lines of:

> `Artisan::queue('Some:method')->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('default')->delay(0);`